# awk error while running script using VBA

Tags: bash, vba, awk, cygwin

I have a bash script which works ok when I run it normally (using cygwin window). The code below:

```
B=$2 #(ie. B="50602_15:56:31_15:56:11_15:56:21")

for line in ${B//;/ } ;
do  
     TENT=`echo ${line} | awk '{split($0,numbers,"_"); print numbers[1]}'`"_sim_fills.txt"
done
```

Now I am trying to run this script using vba in excel:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim cmd As String
    Dim ret As Double
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim plink_object As Object

    ' Run Linux Commands
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set plink_object = WshShell.Run("C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe fills_new.sh 66 ""50602_15:56:31_15:56:11_15:56:21;50602_15:57:07_15:56:47_15:56:57""", 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I got an error: "`awk: command not found`".
Any ideas?

Comment: Try providing the full path to `awk` in the script.

Comment: I would suggest that `c:\cygwin\bin` should be in windows' path, so that any other commands which you might add in future would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BroSlow suggested I used full path to awk and it works ok.

```
B=$2 #(ie. B="50602_15:56:31_15:56:11_15:56:21")

for line in ${B//;/ } ;
do  
     TENT=`echo ${line} | "/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/awk" '{split($0,numbers,"_"); print numbers[1]}'`"_sim_fills.txt"
done
```